# Build Eclipse CDT project in docker

Tags: eclipse, docker, eclipse-cdt

There is docker support in Eclipse CDT. https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn87

I see how to run and debug C++ App in Docker container, but I cannot build project in container, only on my host. Then I have "error while loading shared libraries".

Have you reciepes how can to build Eclips CDT C++ project in container?

Comment: Improper statements. Not a proper english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building in containers is an upcoming feature. The current expectation is that it will be delivered in CDT 9.3 shipping in June 2017. In fact the most recent [CDT monthly call](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/calls/Mar2017) referred to this.

> - CDT 9.3
>
>   - Jeff to add container build support to CDT
>
>     - The goal is to build, run and debug using Container
>     - Support for windows as well as Linux
>     - Intel is also looking into that

Comment: Desperately waiting for that feature. This will make it possible to cross-compile and -debug in a transparent fashion, especially putting qemu in the mix.

Comment: @nucleon this is a very active area at the moment. I highly recommend getting involved so that the end result suits your needs. Follow [Bug 513589](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513589).

Comment: Is there any work on making indexing working too? Cause when you build inside docker there's no need to install anything locally and all headers... just wondering

Comment: @DenisC Yes, the intention AFAIU is to have a fully working system with all the same features supported. Best to follow along on [Bug 513589](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=513589) to see if your use case is supported.